# Is it possible to disable push notification sounds from within my app on iOS 7?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, push-notification, apple-push-notifications

Users of my app have asked to allow them to disable the **sound** for push notifications.
They want to be able to do this from within the app, and not have to go through the Settings->Notification Center->etc. this is too complicated for them - they prefer a simple switch to toggle sound on/off.

To be clear, the **do not want to disable notifications all together**.

I've tried a couple of different ways, non of which seem to work:

1. Trying to "re-register" by calling `- (void)registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:(UIRemoteNotificationType)` again with `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound` omitted. **didnt work**
2. unregister and register by Calling `- (void)unregisterForRemoteNotifications` and registering again (with above call) without the `UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound`. **also didn't work**

Is this even possible? If so how?

Also, I can't really use the "sound" key (to maybe send a silent/empty sound) for the JSON in the push message  itself because I'm using Amazon SNS to send the push to an entire "Topic" - so i can't really customize the message per user (those who disabled the sound vs. those who didn't), in fact I actually don't even have the info at the server-side.

Comment: Did you get solutions?

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure that in the service you are using to send the push notifications to your app users. Register for push notifications part simply registers the device to receive notification.

You can read more about what you can send along with a push notification at Apple developer website: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html

Answer (score 0):

It certainly requires a server-side solution for the problem. I assume you have an API for enabling-disabling the push notification, make one just like that but for the sound and store that in your database if the user wants sound or not. 

Then, for the actual sound-no sound thing there are 2 approaches:

- First is to try and don't send a 'sound' key in the push payload, some people say it works but Apple states it doesn't in their docs
- The second - which I'm sure works - is to set a sound, and on the client side include a sound file which is silent then set that file's name from the server as 'sound'